# How to get all rows having same column values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table called `items` where I store items . Many of the item have same name but different `barcode` and `item_id` . How can I get all the rows from `items` table which has a same name . I want something like this as a result

```
Item1 , .. 24 ,....97982828282
Item1 ,.... 34 , .....987829286
Item3 ,.... 44 , .....987829284
Item3 ,.... 54 , .....987829280
```

Comment: Why not orderBy 'name'?

Comment: use product id column as identifier, you can group by using product id in php or mysql

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table t1
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
               FROM table t2
               WHERE t1.name = t2.name
                 AND ( t1.barcode != t2.barcode
                       OR
                       t1.item_id != t2.item_id )
             );
```